# Target value with torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss should be 0 or -1?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have a multi-label classification problem (A single sample can be classified as several classes at the same time).

I want to use [torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss.html#torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss) but I got confused with the documentation where the ground truth are written like this :

```
Target: (N, C)(N,C) , label targets padded by -1 ensuring same shape as the input.
```

Does that mean the target is in one hot form, but the zero replace with -1?

Let's say I want to classified several attributes for object detection such as : `Man`, `Tall`, `Long hair`.
My first image is a tall woman with long hair, does my Target become `0 1 1` or `-1 1 1` ? I can't fathom why use `-1` instead of `0`

It's quite hard to find example in internet since a lot of people mistook multi-label task as multiple class classification and keep using BCELoss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closer at the [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss.html#torch.nn.MultiLabelSoftMarginLoss):

[image]

The targets are expected to be `{0, 1}` and not -1.
I'm not sure what this -1 is doing, it might be for "ignore", but you are correct that the doc there is not very clear.

There is an [open issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/36217) on pytorch's github about this. Feel free to contribute.